# Tower of Hanoi with adjacent restriction

Tags: python, algorithm

solving [tower of hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_hanoi) with adjacent restriction. 
I tried to look around but I couldn't find any leads to it.

What i've tried so far is:

```py
def hanoi(n, source, helper, target):
    print "hanoi( ", n, source, helper, target, " called"
    if n>0:
        hanoi(n-1, source, helper, target)
        if source[0]:
             if source[0][-1] == 1:
                 move(source, helper)
                 move(helper, target)
        else:
            move(source, helper)
            hanoi(n-1, target, helper, source)
    hanoi(n-1, helper, target, source)
    hanoi(n-1, source, helper, target)

def move(s, d):
    disk = s[0].pop()
    print "moving " + str(disk) + " from " + s[1] + " to " + d[1]
    d[0].append(disk)

source = ([2,1], "source")
target = ([], "target")
helper = ([], "helper")
hanoi(len(source[0]),source,helper,target)
```

which only works for 2 disks.
Thanks

I found this nice math explanation http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~chi/csc2110-2009/notes/T10.pdf

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about what the "adjacent restriction" is?

Comment: moves can only be done from an adjacent tower, so if I want to go from A->C => A->B->C

Comment: The algorithm for solving this is given in [this article](https://tmft.wordpress.com/category/genre/puzzle/tower-of-hanoi/page/2/). I could try writing this in Python, but I don't understand what "source" represents here.

Comment: thanks, I'll read it. Source is the first tower, helper the second and target the last.

Comment: @momigi by your explanation of adjacent this cannot be solved

Comment: correction: this cannot be solved for more than 2 discs and only 3 rods

Comment: @catalesia, I am curious Why? the math behind it is well explained here http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~chi/csc2110-2009/notes/T10.pdf
suppose there is 3 towers ABC, I want to move n disks from A to C. each disk can only be moved from an adjacent tower i.e: A-B or B-C ...

Comment: @momigi Alright, I think I understand the algorithm in the PDF, one last question. What is n? You seem to have placed an upper bound of n moves to transfer a stack of n discs, whereas it actually takes many more moves than that. catalesia, this is entirely possible for an arbitrary number of discs.

Comment: n is the number of disks in the source tower

Comment: @momigi right I should have read it first ;) I misunderstood the adjacent restriction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A verbose implementation

At first glance it looks as if you had to distinguish the case where you can move directly from the current source to the current target, and those where you have to move the biggest disk in two steps. The following implementation does that:

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self, index, name, disks):
        self.index = index
        self.name = name
        self.disks = disks
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Stack(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.index, self.name, self.disks)
    def is_adjacent(self, other):
        return other.index in (self.index + 1, self.index - 1)
    def push(self, disk):
        assert len(self.disks) == 0 or self.disks[-1] > disk
        self.disks.append(disk)
    def pop(self):
        return self.disks.pop()

class Hanoi(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        source = Stack(0, "source", range(n, 0, -1))
        helper = Stack(1, "helper", [])
        target = Stack(2, "target", [])
        self.stacks = [source, helper, target]
        self.hanoi(n, source, target)

    def hanoi(self, n, source, target):
        """Move n disks from source to target using remaining stack"""
        helper = self.stacks[3 - source.index - target.index]
        if n == 0:
            return
        if source.is_adjacent(target):
            self.hanoi(n - 1, source, helper)
            self.move(source, target)
            self.hanoi(n - 1, helper, target)
        else:
            assert helper.is_adjacent(source) and helper.is_adjacent(target)
            self.hanoi(n - 1, source, target)
            self.move(source, helper)
            self.hanoi(n - 1, target, source)
            self.move(helper, target)
            self.hanoi(n - 1, source, target)

    def move(self, s, d):
        assert s.is_adjacent(d)
        disk = s.pop()
        print "moving %d from %s to %s" % (disk, s, d)
        d.push(disk)

Hanoi(5)
```

The `Stack` object helps to keep all the things about one of your stacks together: the name, the position and with that the adjacency, and the current sequence of disks. You could use tuples if you added a third element to hold that index, but I consider OOP to be more intuitive.

The `Hanoi` class keeps together a set of stacks. This allows the `hanoi` method to just specify source and target, while the third stack is inferred. You could code this differently, but I find that omitting the helper makes these recursive calls a lot easier to understand: now for both the single-disk `move` and the multi-disk `hanoi` you specify source and destination, and no third stack.

## Room for simplification

Now if you do a closer look you will find that the recursive calls are always for non-adjacent stacks. So if your stack order is indeed such that source and targets are non-adjacent, then all recursive calles will use the `else` branch of my code, and you can shorten things to avoid the case distinction and always use that `else` branch. I find the more verbose code above easier to understand, in terms of what's going on, though.